# Send request to the API depending on method

Tags: python, python-requests

I have a method of an APIClient class. And I need to optimize if-else statements to handle all HTTP methods without using conditions hierarchy. How I can do this? I tried to use a dictionary, but it doesn't seem like the right way to do

```
      def make_request(self, method: str, request_url: str, data: dict=None, headers=None):
            url = self._build_url(request_url)
            try:
                if method == 'POST':
                    resp = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers, verify=False)
                elif method == 'GET':
                    resp = requests.get(url, headers=headers, verify=False)
                return resp
    
            except requests.exceptions.RequestException:
                raise APINotRespondingeError()
```

Answer (score 1):

I used getattr() method. Note, that method parameter should be in lowercase

```
      def make_request(self, method: str, request_url: str, data: dict=None):
            url = self._build_url(request_url)
            try:
                get_response = getattr(requests, method, None)
                response =  get_response(url, data=data, headers=self.headers)
                response.raise_for_status()
                return response.json()
    
            except requests.exceptions.RequestException as err:
                status_code = None if err.response is None else err.response.status_code
                raise APIResponseError(error=err)
```